# Return data of Numpys FFT and finding amplitude and frequencies per second in audio file

Tags: python, numpy, audio, fft

For the past few days I have been learning about reading wav files for an audio visualizer project I am doing in python. The Project is going well but I have a few questions about the data that gets returned from reading the wavfile and the return of the array of complex numbers from the np.fft.fft()

So just starting off what does the complex number represent? The real and imaginary part?

My Real Question is here:
I was also told that the frequency is the index position of the complex number is this True?

After loading an audio file and running it through FFT, I for example can get an arrray with a length of 10591232, A Really Large number, My thought process is to take that number and divide it by the audios sample rate in order to get a list of the frequencies being used per second

Is this thinking wrong? if so what should be done instaed? I will post my code below to show my thinking there as well, Sorry for such a loaded question I have been searching through countless StackOverflow posts and have gotten alot of different answers. Thanks Again For Reading!

```py
sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(sound_file)

channel_num = data.shape[1]
audio_length = data.shape[0] / sample_rate
time = np.linspace(0., audio_length, data.shape[0])

frequencies = np.fft.fft(time)
frequencies_per_second = np.array_split(frequencies, len(frequencies) / sample_rate)

pprint(len(frequencies_per_second[1]))
print(len(frequencies))
```

Comment: This question shows such a broad misunderstanding of FFTs and audio frequency analysis in general that a short introductory chapter of some textbook would be required to fix your knowledge, far too much to fit in this comment box.  Besides, I'll bet you're actually interested in pitch, not FFT frequency, which are not the same thing.

Comment: Would you be willing to at least explain what you can at the very least pertaining to the question? Its awesome that your telling me I have no knowledge in the subject, that much is obvious but I would at least like a starting off point. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) is used because that is a mathematically elegant way to represent both the magnitude and phase of each DFT result.

The bin or element index of an FFT result vector correlates with the frequency of a transform basis vector.  Usually, for the first half of the FFT result vector:

```
basis_vector_frequency = index * sample_rate / FFT_length
```

However the frequency of each transform basis vector may or may not exactly match the frequency of some constituent of an input signal, due to windowing effects.